# Java: New frame before lauching main app

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to add a new frame to my program. Now use a simple Confirm Dialog (yes/no) to set some variables, but I'd like the variables be configurable.

This is how it works: Execute --> Confirm Dialog --> "Main"

What I want : Execute --> Confirmation Frame --> "Main"

I've already created a new frame, I declare in the main, but when launches it doesn't load the components, just the new frame window and freezes. (Use thread with join and wait/notify).

How and where should I create the new frame?

Edit:

```
private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

    //Now
    /*int n= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        mainPanel.getParent(),
        "Question",
        "Q",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);*/


    //Should I create the frame here?
    newF = new newFrame();
    newF.setVisible(true);
    newF.setLocationRelativeTo(mainPanel);

    ...
}
```

The problem with this way is that both windows are launched.

Comment: You should do it next time to EDT finished processing the next cycle event.

Comment: Before we can help you, you have to show us some code first. What isn't working for you?

Comment: `JOptionPane` and a modal `JDialog.show()` have special handling when they are run in a way that blocks the event dispatch thread, they create another EDT of their own to use while the main one is blocked.  `JFrame` doesn't, so you should take care not to block the EDT - instead of waiting you should think async and do the post-confirmation logic in a suitable event handler (e.g. register a `WindowListener` on your confirm frame and do the processing in `windowClosing`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instructional example of how to do window chaining.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Window j1 = new JDialog() {
        {
            setTitle("Frame One");
            setSize(250, 250);
            setLocation(100, 100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setModal(true);
        }
    };

    final Window j2 = new JFrame() {
        {
            setTitle("Frame Two");
            setSize(250, 250);
            setLocation(350, 100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    };

    // Will block here until the 1st window is dismissed.
    j1.setVisible(true);


    // Will not block 
    j2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how could I use it. The structure is: exampleApp -> launch exampleView (extends FrameView). The code that I wrote is in exampleView .

Comment: I was not expecting you to use my example directly in your program.  My example shows you how to chain two windows.  J1 is the 1st window that will display. It is what you are calling "Confirmation Frame".  The 2nd, J2, is what you are calling "Main".

Comment: I tried your example with 2 frames (instead of Jdialog), but both appears together.

Comment: My example is not two frames.  My example is 1 JDialog and 1 JFrame.  Try again.  They do not appear together.  The 2nd appears after the 1st is dismissed.

Comment: Ok, I changed the JFrame to a JDialog, and now it's working. The only thing is that I see the components with the old java style in the JDialog.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working. You should create a new question for the new problem.